# Check when "done" button is pressed on ios keypad

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I have a modal in my screen, which has an input box. What i want is when user presses "return" or "done" button in ios keypad , i want my input to go an redux action, so what i am doing is

[image: Refer here to see ios keypad]

```
<input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Type a message"
      onChange={e => setMessage(e)}
      onKeyDown={e => keyDown(e)}
      value={inputText}
                />
```

then

```
const keyDown = e => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      dispatch(userResponseChat(inputText));
      setInputText("");
    }
  };
```

so for now it works well on android keypad and ios keypad when we press "return" button,
but is there any way i could trigger the same when user click on "done" button in reactjs?

Comment: [Many many attempts](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+detect+ios+done+keyboard+site:stackoverflow.com) - consensus seems to listen for focusout

Comment: @mplungjan sorry the link doesnt work :\

Comment: Which link. I posted [many links](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+detect+ios+done+keyboard+site:stackoverflow.com) - and if they do not work, then it is likely impossible

Comment: @mplungjan those didnt worked out,tried with onblur too , but my case is little different, the focus has to be on input field cause its like a chat ui. Please help :(

Comment: Little different how? I reopened the question